# How to set Deny all to Access Restriction of Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I'm missing deny all rules. I need make sure that only Azure services can call Azure Functions.
How to configure?

I find "Add rule". Action would be "Deny".

"What to select as "Type" and "Source Address"?

How to make sure Azure services like ADF can access Functions.

Answer (score 0):

> "What to select as "Type" and "Source Address"?

In the Type you need to select as **Service Tag** and in the **Service Tag** area you can declare any of the service which you want to allow either it might be **App Service** or it might be **Data Factory**. As per the below image.

[image]

[image]

Once you allow particular service rest all will go under Deny automatically.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWrGA.png]

Comment: If my answer is helpful could you please accept my answer so that it would be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues